# view like facebook time line in android

Tags: android, android-view

I am new to android. 
I am creating a application where the notes shall appear in the timeline as like as facebook. Please help me out how to create such view.

Comment: Hi Mike, I was able to show till the horizantal scroll of the icons, under the icons i should be able to display the date/month of the created notes.. i was stopped over there

Comment: Its hard to understand what that means , can you please post some relevant code .

Answer (score 1):

Use a [List view](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) with a custom adapter.

The custom adapter should extend [BaseAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html), and in the [getView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView%28int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29) method [inflate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3477643/492561) the a view for each list item. Be sure to checkout this [technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11840582/492561) to prevent Out of memory errors

Have methods in the adapter which allow you to add more data. Then when you update the data call [notifyDataSetChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29) to update the view.

Comment: I tried till showing the notes in the horizantal scroll.. but am in fixation how to show the time line under the icons....